# Al escribir sobre un archivo de texto en lenguaje C me aparecen símbolos en lugar de letras

Tags: c, archivo, crud

No sé si la razón por la cual me aparecen estos símbolos en mi archivo es por el uso de la función fwrite en lugar de fprintf y si ese es el caso, cómo podría cambiarlo?
El programa funciona bien fuera de eso, no hay ningún otro inconveniente más, sólo que mi profesor me pide que el archivo pueda ser leído por él para que compruebe que efectivamente estoy haciendo un correcto uso de los archivos desde mi programa.  Tuve que cortar el código para que me dejara publicar la pregunta, pero eran básicamente más "atributos" de una estructura tales como: nombre, fecha de registro, etc..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct fecha
{
    int AAAA;
    int MM; 
    int DD;
}fecha;

typedef struct cliente
{
    int idCliente;
    char Nombre[30];
    char ApPaterno[30];
    char ApMaterno[30];
    fecha date;
    double Credito;
    double Deuda;
}cliente;
void Crear()
{
    cliente c;
    char otro;
    FILE *fp;

    do{
    printf("\t\t\t\t=======Escribe la informacion del Cliente=======\n\n\n"); 
    fp = fopen("Clientes.txt","a");
  
        printf("\nIntroduce la deuda del cliente: ");
        scanf("%lf",&c.Deuda);
            if(!ValidarDeuda(c.Deuda))
            {
                printf("\nDeuda no valida, adios.\n");
                break;
            }
        printf("\nDeuda valida.");
        printf("\n\t\t\t______________________________\n");

    if(fp == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr,"\nNo se puede abrir el archivo.");
    else 
        printf("\t\t\tRegistro guardado satisfactoriamente.");

    
    fwrite(&c, sizeof(cliente), 1, fp); 

    fclose(fp);

    printf("\n\t\t\tQuieres agregar otro registro? (s/n): ");
    scanf("%s",&otro);

    }while(otro == 'S' || otro == 's');
}
```

Comment: deberías añadir la declaración de `cliente` al código de la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La línea:

```c
fwrite(&c, sizeof(cliente), 1, fp);
```

Escribe los bytes que haya dentro de la estructura `cliente` al disco. En tu caso la estructura tiene diferentes campos de diferentes tipos, como se observa en su declaración:

```
typedef struct cliente
{
    int idCliente;
    char Nombre[30];
    char ApPaterno[30];
    char ApMaterno[30];
    fecha date;
    double Credito;
    double Deuda;
}cliente;
```

Algunos de esos campos son arrays de `char`, pero otros son `int` o `double`. Los arrays de `char` contienen dentro códigos ASCII de las letras, mientras que otros campos contienen representaciones binarias en un formato que depende de la arquitectura de la máquina.

Cuando se vuelca a disco con `fwrite()` no se transforman los bytes de ninguna forma, sino que directamente se copian de la memoria al disco, en el mismo orden en que se hallaran en memoria. Al final el fichero contiene una secuencia de bytes.

Cuando abres el fichero con un editor de texto, éste espera que cada byte del fichero represente un carácter. Eso es así para algunos de los campos (por ejemplo `Nombre`) pero no es así en otros. Por ejemplo imagina que el `idCliente` (que es un entero) vale 64. En memoria ese entero se almacena en 4 bytes que en una arquitectura Intel irían en el siguiente orden:

```
64 0 0 0
```

siendo el primero la parte más "baja" del dato (64) y los otros la parte más alta (que en este caso son 0 porque el número es menor de 255 y cabe en un solo byte).

El caso es que cuando el editor vea esa secuencia la interpretará como: el carácter con código 64 seguido del carácter con código 0, y otro de código 0, etc... Estos caracteres son respectivamente la `@` (su código es el 64) y el ASCII NULO (su código es 0). Por lo que al editar el fichero (o volcarlo por una terminal) se verá una @ y una serie de NUL (aunque dependiendo de la terminal o del editor puede elegir no mostrar nada para los NUL).

Eso explica por qué ves "cosas raras" en el fichero.

### Solución

Si lo que pretendes es que se vea algo legible en el fichero, tu programa tiene que ocuparse de la conversión. La forma más sencilla es usar `fprintf()` que convierte a una secuencia ASCII cada cosa. Por ejemplo así:

```
fprintf(fp, "Id: %d\n", c.idCliente);
fprintf(fp, "Nombre: %s\n", c.Nombre);
// ...
fprintf(fp, "Deuda: %f\n", c.Deuda);
```

Observa cómo en cada `fprintf()` hay que especificar de qué tipo es el campo que estás convirtiendo (`%d` para enteros, `%f` para doubles, etc)

Lo que volcará entonce `fprintf()` al fichero será una representación ASCII de esas cantidades. Eso es en el fondo otra serie de bytes, pero ahora esos bytes son códigos de caracteres que al editar el fichero leerás correctamente.

El fichero mostraría algo como:

```
Id: 23
Nombre: Manolo
...
Deuda: 2300.25
```

**CUIDADO** Aunque ahora el fichero es mucho más legible para personas, resulta más difícil de leer para otro programa. Tienes que "parsear" el contenido del fichero leyéndolo línea a línea, separando buscando el `:` e interpretando lo que va después al formato correcto usando `fscanf()`.

Si estos registros que vuelcas a disco vas a necesitar leerlos después desde otro programa, yo te recomendaría que no hicieras nada de esto, sino que lo dejaras como estaba con `fwrite()` pues entonces será más fácil de leer con un `fread()`. Si usaras un lenguaje de más alto nivel (no C), podrías usar otros formatos de representación de información, como JSON, que tienen la ventaja de ser legibles por personas (pues en el fondo son cadenas ASCII), pero también ser legibles por los programas, a través de un parser JSON que muchos lenguajes tienen ya integrado (pero no el C).